# SWI-Prolog plugin on Sublime build error

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, sublimetext3

I know this is kinda stupid question, but I am really despaired now, because I cant find the way to build it. I always get this error

```
ERROR: call/2: Undefined procedure: main/1
ERROR:   However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         main/0
```

Even though I tried

```
father(ahmad,samer).
father(ahmad,lolo).
father(ahmad,koko).


grandfather(X,Y):-
    father(U,X),
    father(Y,U).

main :- father(ahmad, X), writef('%t\n', [X]).
```

So can someone help me to do it the right way ?

Comment: How do you call main ? That's the problem...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works just fine for me.

Just type `main.` 
Don't forget the `.`,otherwise it won't run.
Here is what I got

```
2 ?- main.
samer
true ;
lolo
true ;
koko
true.
```

After `true` type `;` instead of pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button if you want to show all three names. If you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, only the first name will appear.

From your code I figured out that `ahmad` is the father,so about the `grandfather` query, I think I has to be this way:

```
granfather(X,Y):- father(X,U),father(U,Y).
```

Because on your `father` query the `father` is on the left

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but do I have to write it like this `main :- father(ahmad, X), writef('%t\n', [X]).` i mean, there got to be a way to deal with it like in eclipse PDT, in other words, where can i write queries ?

Comment: What do you mean 'where can you write queries' ?
You mean where(in what program) you can write your code?

Comment: There is another way to write the code,without writing `main`. Just write the father and grandfather queries and then run the program and type `father(ahmad,X).` You'll get the same results.

Comment: @AmbiguousTk I don't know of a Sublime plug-in that facilitates normal interaction with the SWI top level. When I used Sublime, I just ran swipl in a terminal and reloaded the file whenever I wanted to test something or pose a query. That worked fine for me. I must admit, however, that I enjoy the extra frills offered by prolog-mode since I switched to emacs.

Comment: @NickLee I meant that if it is possible to query in sublime, regardless the swi-prolog in terminal, or PDT plugin for eclipse.

Comment: @AmbiguousTk Ι've never used sublime, so I don't know, sorry. All I do is write the code in notepad++ then run the `.pl` file with SWI-Prolog.